# Android draggable horizontal custom menu

Tags: android-layout, android

Can I create custom horizontal menu in android? I mean something like this:
[image]

I want to be able select level and drag level by finger.
What methods should i use?
`LinearLayout` with `android.orientation="horizontal"`, or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides a `HorizontalScrollView` for this.

For more information visit the [Developers guidelines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)